# What is trimmable "peaking"?

Tags: operational-amplifier, control, feedback, mosfet-driver, resonance

I'm studying Jim Williams application note [AN-104 - Load Transient Response Testing for Voltage Regulators](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an104f.pdf), in which he describes an FET-based load transient generator, what might commonly be called an *electronic load* or *dummy load*.

In the highlighted areas, Jim mentions "peaking" components:

[image]

[image]

And apparently, when properly adjusted, these *peaking trimmers* allow the circuit to produce a very clean-edged and flat output (current through the MOSFET, trace B):

[image]

*Note the [LT1210](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1210fb.pdf) is a **current feedback** amplifier, not one of the perhaps more familiar voltage feedback variety.*

My question is: ***"What is the peaking Jim is talking about here and how does trimming it optimize this circuit's output waveform?"***

I vaguely suspect it has something to do with adjusting the resonant frequency of the gate drive node (and separately the feedback network) to push just the right amount of charge into the MOSFET gate at the fastest possible speed, but really don't have much of a clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to the amplifier, and is perhaps best illustrated by the gain characteristics into a capacitive load:

[image: LT1210 Gain characteristics]

The flattest curve is when Rf is somewhere around 1.5k, and that is what is in the load circuit (1k trim, 560 ohm fixed), As the circuit will vary with parts (particularly the amplifier and FET), this needs to be trimmed for flattest response. Note that this trim is for capacitive load peaking (or in reality, *de*-peaking).

The *loop* peaking trim sets the loop gain for transient response.

This amplifier (ignoring DC offset for now) is a follower at steady state, but has some gain for transient performance (Rg is only effectively in circuit for transient events). To get just the right gain for fast loop performance, but maintaining low peaking of the gain performance, this ac gain needs to be adjustable as well; hence the loop peaking adjustment.

Note that the graph shows best peaking compensation performance at a gain of 6dB, and the Rf and Rg values show the gain will be somewhere in this ballpark area.

The gate drive peaking is to adjust the current available by limiting to *just enough* drive; this gives sufficient drive to drive the FET, but limits the effect of gate capacitance to a manageable level.

All these adjustments are simply because driving a power FET gate requires some compensation to account for capacitive loading, and is why these are not present in the subsequent bipolar circuit.

The 2.5Ω resistor and 10μF ceramic device appear to be the damping circuit referred to in the text.

Comment: Ah! **De**-peaking! Now it makes sense :) Very clear answer Peter, very helpful indeed, thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the gate capacitance is driven by a voltage divider, output impedance about 2.5 ohms (that's what the 2.5 ohm resistor and 10 uF capacitor are for), and
that keeps the rise time (R*C) short.  The raw op amp output impedance is higher (40 ohms, perhaps?). That part, is just trading off the slew rate and output
voltage range (excess to needs) to get lower drive resistance.  As for the 'loop peaking' capacitor, it reduces the negative feedback.  This steals back some of the gain reduction that one needs for feedback compensation, and will result in oscillation if you go too far, so the 1k variable resistor is there, to tweak the feedback if it does oscillate.  That tweak is done while looking at a response curve, and dialed until the peak is flat...